# How to make long command in IMAP?

Tags: imap, uid

I want to make a long command with FETCH that gives me :
1.What is UID ?
2.What is attachment ?
and other things

Comment: Read RFC3501, it contains everything you want (and need) to know regarding IMAP at this point.

Answer (score 1):

What other things? Pretty much all metadata:
`tag FETCH 1 (uid flags envelope bodystructure internaldate)`

Answer (score 0):

you question is not clear. but i assume you want to retrieve all the data.
use following command

```
A FETCH 1:* ALL
```